# Uninformative questions get lots of upvotes

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes

Why do simple questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173463/why-does-i-i-i-give-me-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375932/why-does-java-think-that-the-product-of-all-numbers-from-10-to-99-is-0) get so many upvotes? The titles of these questions are so specific that, in the future, no one would ever search fro this to find their answer, if they had a similar problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read some more on the [Bikeshed problem and how it affects SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange).

Basically because the question is "easy" a lot of people can see whether it's a good question or not and vote accordingly. Harder, more obscure questions which may be "better" questions will gain fewer votes because fewer people understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link it was very helpful, and I learned something here, but I'm still not satisfied and I still think it is unfair.

Comment: @AliAmiri [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå nice touch ;)

Answer (score -1):

More people know about the simpler things, which means that the knowledge about obscure questions is almost always focused in a few developers. Maybe there could be a level, to value votes differently.

Comment: ok, no more opinions